# how to adjust position of an element after showing header and footer bar in iPhone safari

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

The version of iPhone that I use is 7.0.4
I use javascript to calculate the position of the loading image and make it show in the middle of "available" area in Safari.
Here's the problem :
When the phone change its position vertical to horizontal,I can use the **resize** event to keep the image in the middle of screen(without touch screen)(①-②).
Next touch the screen the header bar and foot bar show and the loading image is no longer in the middle of "available" area(blue square area of ③)(②-③).
I wanna know if there's some event triggered when the header and footer bar shows so that I can bind it and adjust the position of the image? Or is there some other solution to make it ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could use media queries in your CSS to do this. You would just need to have all your break points in the CSS. I don't believe there is an event that you can tap into to see if the bars are shown as this is the native browser.